# Android custom view getForeground() returns null even though it's set in xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with my embedded custom view not respecting `setClickable(false)`.

I want it to stop having the ripple effect visible and I'm trying to get the foreground drawable and set it to invisible but it's `null` throughout the entire life of the fragment.

The foreground drawable is set in the xml, I don't know why `getForeground()` doesn't return it.

(To get the same effect I wanted to use selectors with `state_active` as the determining variable but I've read that it's used somewhere by Android so I've abstained from using it. My own introduced `state_enable_ripple` didn't have the effect I wanted it to have.)

This is the custom view's layout file which I use to inflate my view instance.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_colors">

    <ProgressBar/>

    <Button />

</FrameLayout>
```

```
    @Override
    public void setClickable(boolean clickable) {
        super.setClickable(clickable);
        Timber.d("foreground %s", getForeground());
        Timber.d("foreground tint %s", getForegroundTintList());
        if (getForeground() != null) {
            Timber.d("i co");
            getForeground().mutate().setVisible(clickable, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any custom `View` anywhere. I see a `<FrameLayout>` that has the described attributes, but since it's just the regular platform class, the given code cannot work with it since that's internal `View` code. Also, if that code is assuming that the foreground will be set from `android:foreground="..."` by the time that `setClickable()` is called for `android:clickable="false"`, you really shouldn't assume that.

Comment: The FrameLayout is embedded somewhere else as the custom view.

The xml code represents the custom view's layout file.

Why I shouldn't assume that foreground is set? When instantiating the view I inflate the sub-views and bing it with Butterknife. I'm also calling it waaay into the life of the view.

Comment: Those attributes are not on your custom `<View>`. They're on that `<FrameLayout>`. You cannot get the foreground on that `FrameLayout` by calling `getForeground()` on your custom `View`. You would have to call `getForeground()` on that `FrameLayout`. If those attributes are meant to be in your custom `<View>`, then you need to move them there. Furthermore, if your custom `View` is a `FrameLayout` subclass, then you probably don't want that `<FrameLayout>` at all, but rather `<merge>` tags, though the attributes would still need moved.

Comment: As for the other thing, why would you think that `android:foreground` will definitely be set _before_  `android:clickable`? Or do you mean to be calling `setClickable()` separately yourself somewhere? I'm not really sure what the goal is there.

Comment: I am also calling setClickable() somewhere else, later. But yeah, you are right that I shouldn't assume the foreground will be set when clickable will be set during inflation(?). That's why there's a null check though, but it's my fault I didn't bring it up earlier. My custom view is a FrameLayout subclass. I've changed the tag to ```<merge>``` now and I've moved the tags to the place where the custom view is used. I now am able to get the foreground as I wanted. I think you can submit an answer and I will accept it. (The foreground doesn't do what I wanted it to do but it's accessible now.)

Comment: Yeah, OK, you do see what I meant, as far as the attribute order. After the `super` constructor call, both of those attributes will have been set by then, so you could do adjustments after that in your constructor; you just shouldn't assume anything otherwise. Also yep, inflation is the proper term there. Anyhoo, glad you got that worked out. I didn't really do much except point out the (common) confusion between a custom `View` and its internal layout, so probably not worth a whole answer. :-) Please feel free to answer yourself, if you like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!